# Где лежит шаблон пустой корзины в Битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс, корзина

Подскажите какой файл править чтобы поменять шаблон пустой корзины компонента `bitrix:sale.basket.basket`, шаблон всей корзины я скопировал и переделал (это старая корзина) . Файла empty.php в ней нет. 
Сейчас на сайте красная надпись `"Ваша корзина пуста"`
Может кто-то сталкивался

Answer (score -3):

Похоже, что да, в новом движке (с 18той версии) [всё немного иначе](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/magazin/basket/sale_basket_basket.php) и файл нужно *создавать самостоятельно*.

> С версии 18.1.0 модуля Интернет-магазин в составе шаблона .default
>   доступна новая страница empty.php. Теперь при переходе в пустую
>   корзину будет отображаться содержимое страницы empty.php вместо
>   стандартной надписи "Корзина пуста". Кастомизируя шаблон, можно
>   настроить собственное описание пустой корзины.

Поэтому:

- проверяете что версия модуля у вас такая какая есть
- если файла нет, то создаёте его.

Comment: не совсем то, мне нужно переправить не константу с надписью, а верстку самого шаблона